# Translation Icon Missing in Transposh

Tags: wordpress, plugins, checkout

I am using transposh plugin. I have done translation into multilingual except a single page, checkout page, using this plugin.

It will display a translation Icon while loading. after finishing loading it will hide the icon. So I can't make a translation

Here I have attached the link of both Scenarios.

**While loading it shows the icon:**

[image]

**After loading the icon disappear:**

[image]